# iOS Facebook fql request to return photo url

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-fql, sdwebimage

My query string looks like this : `NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id, name, pic, type, url, username from profile where id = %@", sourceID];`

I finally get the profile. In my app, I want to show the profile pic. So I take the string out of the "pic" parameter. The url is very weird though. It looks something like this : `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash1/t5/1209883_196371450373992_763018152_s.jpg`

On google, people say that akamaihd is a virus. I just don't understand how a fql request can return to me an url that is linked to a virus... Please help!

I also want to add that the SDWebImage framework doesn't return an image at all. But, if I copy paste this url in my browser, it shows me the exact image I want to get. I don't understand at all what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have the facebook user id, so you actually don't need to perform another FQL request.
All you need to do to get the profile picture url is to do:

```
NSString *profilePictureURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=100&height=100", userId];
```

then, use this url to load a user profile pic.

Comment: Omg yes... I don't know why I didn't see that. Thank you very much! :)